# DAVx5: Change Base URL of all Calendars

Tags: macos, android, webserver, webdav, caldav

I had installed CALDAV server (Radicale) on my old laptop, but now I don't have access to  that machine. I had synced calendars hosted by the caldav server to my android using DAVx5. Now, on my new machine I have installed a CALDAV server (Xandikos), and I would like to sync the existing CALDAV calendars on Android that were synced to Radicale be synced to Xandikos. Essentially the base url of each calendar needs to be updated, from http://192.168.178.22:5676/nikhil to http://192.168.178.33:8899/users/calendars.

Any suggestions?

---

[image: Screenshot_20220708-140148_DAVx]

---

## Steps that I tried

1. I created folder `mkdir -p /Users/lamyergeier/dav/nikhil/calendars`
2. I launched Xadikos with 192.168.178.22 and port 5232: `/Users/lamyergeier/.local/bin/xandikos -d /Users/lamyergeier/dav -l 192.168.178.22 -p 5232`

### Observation

On the browser http://192.168.178.22:5232 doesn't load the web interface! and it shows Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 192.168.178.22:5232.

Comment: I would be surprised if you could sync calendars from the old to the new server by just changing the URL in the CALDAV client. The common way would be to export the calendar to ICAL format then import it on the new server. Usually the servers should provide tools for import/export.

Comment: @Robert Isn't it supposed to be 2 way sync?